# Xcode Test Scheme script

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm trying to change various properties for Unit Tests such that the injected known settings will not interfere with various settings when actually running the app (Specifically the keychain but potentially the Bundle Identifier too)

(The way I envision doing this is using a different `kSecAttrAccessGroup` for the Unit Tests based on the `KeyChainService` entry in the plist.)

I also intend using this script with `AppCode`.

The problem is that I can't find anywhere to put the script (or any variables) which will overwrite the normal pre-action script during the build phase which occurs before any Test phase.

My bash script is as follows:

```
 plist="${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}" 
 if [[ "${plist}" == "/" ]]; then
   # AppCode (no variables set)
   plist=./myProject-Info.plist
 fi
 if [[ -z "$csKeyChain" ]]; then
     csKeyChain=RUN
 fi
 if [[ -z "$bundleIdentifier" ]]; then
    bundleIdentifier=com.mycompany.abc
 fi
 
 echo "Setting KeyChainService to $csKeyChain; CFBundleIdentifier to $bundleIdentifier" > ~/BUILD.txt
 /usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set KeyChainService $csKeyChain" "${plist}"
 /usr/libexec/Plistbuddy -c "Set CFBundleIdentifier $bundleIdentifier" "${plist}"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I ended up solving the shared keychain issue was as follows:

Created a singleton wrapper helper class for the KeyChain which sets a "KeyChainIdentifier" property.  This will be used to set a unique kSecAttrService for each different environment when placing values in the KeyChain.

i.e,

```
static CSKeyChain *instance;

+ (void)initialize {
    static BOOL initialized = NO;
    if (!initialized) {
        initialized = YES; {
            NSString *keyChainIdentifier = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:@"KeyChainIdentifier"];
            instance = [[CSKeyChain alloc] initWithKeyChainIdentifier:keyChainIdentifier];
        }
    }
}
```

Then in the Unit Tests setUp() function I added

```
 [CSKeyChain setValue:@"csTest" forKeyPath:@"instance.keyChainIdentifier"];
```

The only other thing I did was ensure when using certificates (kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA), the kSecAttrApplicationTag has the keyChainIdentifier prepended.

Thus, I will be able to run unit tests which will not interfere with normal operation of the App, and in addition by changing both keyChainIdentifier and BundleIdentifier, will be able to run apps for different environments on the same device. BOOM!